# open content related to each of a list item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to j Query.
I am trying to open the content related to each of the list item in a div with id "#employee". The id "#details" should open 1 item at a time and hide the others. I tried myself to achieve this problem but due to my little knowledge I am unable to do.

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbWS5/4/)

```
    <div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee1"><h2>Employee 1</h2><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature </p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee2"><h2>Employee 2</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee3"><h2>Employee 3</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee4"><h2>Employee 4</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>                        
    <div class="thumbs">
        <ul> 
            <li id="employee1">Employe 1</li>
            <li id="employee2">Employe 2</li>                
            <li id="employee3">Employe 3</li>
            <li id="employee4">Employe 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var divname = this.html();
        $("#employee").show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe jQuery UI provides an accordion-type widget that would be perfect here http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: ID should be unique...

Comment: Please post the code you've tried (even if it's wrong, who cares? We all write wrong code), simply saying you've tried and failed without any evidence is...sketchy :D

Comment: @Katstevens, Accordion open the content just below the div. I don't think so that is the way I want to show it.

Comment: Please put code in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @mbkh10 could you be a bit more specific about where you want the divs to open please?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with simple HTML and CSS, no need for JavaScript. But off course JavaScript is needed for some nice effects. 
This is what I did for my case.

first fixed the height of container so it can show only one item at a time and hide the others. For this I use the following CSS code

```
#container {
height: 100px;
width: 500px;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;}
```

And the HTML look is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="container">
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee1"><h2>Employee 1</h2><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature </p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee2"><h2>Employee 2</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee3"><h2>Employee 3</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div id="employee4"><h2>Employee 4</h2><p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbs">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#employee1">Employe 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#employee2">Employe 2</a></li>                
        <li><a href="#employee3">Employe 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#employee4">Employe 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RqQeC/)